# Ambidextrous mouse in greeter?

Tags: mouse, lightdm

I'm currently running light-dm-greeter, and all is fine, except this computer is shared between left and right handed users. I cannot figure out how to configure light-dm-greeter to allow both left and right handed users to intuitively log in. For proper accessibility, the greeter should treat left and right mouse clicks identically. I am looking for a change that only affects the greeter, as the rest of the system is configured well.

Question: Is it possible to configure light-dm-greeter to treat left and right mouse clicks identically? If so, how? If not, what would be a good lightweight greeter than can?

Comment: to be clear, the question is purely about configuring lightdm greeter for mouse right n left clicks rite.. to make the question to corner, we can ignore xfce part rite??

Comment: Yes, I only mention the xfce part to make clear that I'm not looking for a way to change my mouse system-wide -- everything works perfectly in xfce, I just want light-dm-greeter to work regardless of who is holding the mouse

Comment: thats very clear now..

Comment: @Nmath Telling left handers to not use a mouse, or to use a mouse backwards, is discrimination. Making software so it can be easily used by both left handed or right handed people is not.

Comment: My question is two fold -- can I configure dm-light-greeter to do what I want? If not, what is a good lightweight greeter that can do what I want?  Any further comments suggesting that I should just not want what I want are not desired.

Comment: Have you considered using a one-button mouse?  These are still used for people for people who don't have the dexterity to control each finger individually.  And some people still prefer them.  This kind of mouse would provide total equality for all of your PC users.

Comment: @JimmyBrokaw I have installed lightdm and saw.. I observed that both left and right buttons are doing the same in greeter except at password field entry.. Have you noticed this? To make your question to further corner.. Is your requirement about this, when clicking rite or left mouse button in the password entry field it should activate it and not to show right click menu.. that is copy paste etc..

Comment: @PRATAP When selecting a user, a left click must be used to select who is logging in. That's the biggest frustration right now.

Comment: Hi based on your comments.. I could corner the Question in to one corner and started workarounds on it. Can you tell me how are the left handers configured mouse keys in a running session (after login)?

Comment: @PRATAP Right now, the left handers on my computer configure their xfce session to reverse mouse buttons, while right handers do not. It works perfectly once the session is established. My suggested solution would be to copy the behavior of, I believe, unity-greeter, which treats left and right clicks identically within the greeter... I can't think of any need for a right click within the greeter.

Comment: 0k.. I tried little workarounds.. I am interested in how they configured for left handers.. I mean is there a command or some configuration file or is it a GUI way in logged in session of xfce..

Comment: Within xfce, it's settings->mouse->left-handed. I assume the GUI is just calling xmodmap, but I don't know for sure. Hmmm, come to think of it, xmodmap -e "pointer = 1 1 1" should work if I could run it before the greeter starts, and xmodmap -e "pointer = 1 2 3" after it hands off to the session, but that seems harder than simply allowing right clicks to function as left clicks in the greeter.

Comment: my work around is also the same. But I think we cant give button twice with xmodmap though it is possible to disable the button but physical button and mapping of mouse button twice is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:

Create a script with below content. I have saved the file as `/var/lib/lightdm/1.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

xinput set-button-map 'Dell Dell Universal Receiver Mouse' 1 2 1
```

Change the device name (`Dell Dell Universal Receiver Mouse`) as per your device name.

Create a file with below content, `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`

```
[Seat:*]
greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/bash /var/lib/lightdm/1.sh
```

Create a startup application preference for your users with xfce login session with required changes to below command..

```
xinput set-button-map 'Dell Dell Universal Receiver Mouse' 1 2 3
```

Tested with lightdm greeter and Ubuntu 20.04 default.

Here is the output of `lightdm --show-config`

```
$ lightdm --show-config 
   [Seat:*]
A  allow-guest=false
C  greeter-wrapper=/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-greeter-session
D  guest-wrapper=/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session
E  user-session=ubuntu
F  greeter-session=unity-greeter
G  xserver-command=X -core
H  type=xlocal
H  display-setup-script=/sbin/prime-offload
H  display-stopped-script=/sbin/prime-switch
I  greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/bash /var/lib/lightdm/1.sh

   [LightDM]
B  backup-logs=false

Sources:
A  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-disable-guest.conf
B  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-disable-log-backup.conf
C  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-greeter-wrapper.conf
D  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-guest-wrapper.conf
E  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf
F  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf
G  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-xserver-command.conf
H  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/90-nvidia.conf
I  /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
$
```

Comment: Did not work on my Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS installation -- lightdm-greeter failed to load correctly, and provided a dialog box in low-graphics mode suggesting I check my graphics settings.

Comment: I see you changed it, but using xinput still leaves the greeter unable to load, and forces me to a terminal.

Comment: can you try those xinput commands in a running session and if it is working then only add it to `lightdm.conf` file.

Comment: They work fine within a session -- I can change my mouse to ambidextrous and back without error.  I'm not seeing any relevant errors in teh seat0-greeter.log, either.

Comment: xmodmap or xinput both worked for me in lightdm greeter